# Android ResultReceiver updating views in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, intentservice

I'm trying to update a TextView and a ProgressBar in an Adapter using a Result Receiver and Intent Service, but I'm a bit confused on how to update it.

**Result Receiver:**

```
    private ResultReceiver myRR = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);

            if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {

                int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); //get the progress

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
//                            holder.downloadStatus.setText("Downloading...");
//                            holder.progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                });

//                Log.d(TAG, "onReceiveResult - Adapter: " + progress); // It works

                if (progress == 100) {

                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {

//                        holder.downloadStatus.setText("Downloaded");
//                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(progress);

//                        Glide.with(mContext)
//                            .load(R.drawable.ic_play)
//                            .into(holder.ivEpisodeFile);
//
//                        holder.clDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

**Adapter:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final EpisodeLineHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Episode episodes = episodesList.get(position);
    holder.ivEpisodeFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(mContext, TestService.class);
                    downloadIntent.setAction(ACTION_START_DOWNLOAD);
                    downloadIntent.putExtra("receiver", myRR);
                    downloadIntent.putExtra("url", episodes.getAudioFile());
                    downloadIntent.putExtra("filename", fileName);
            }
    }
}
```

I'm able to receive results in Result Receiver, but I'm not able to update views.
I know that I should update views in `onBindViewHolder`, but how can I do it using the results from Result Receiver?

I'm trying it all day, I've searched all around the web, but I still stuck.

Am I all wrong in this solution?
Also, how can I still updating views when activity is stopped and resumed later? Is that possible?

**EDIT 1**

If I move `myRR` to `onBindViewHolder` it works while activity is running, but when it is stopped and resumed, it stops updating the views.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final EpisodeLineHolder holder, final int position) {
    ResultReceiver myRR = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?